# how to Slow down AI?

Tags: java, android, artificial-intelligence, slowdown

So i'm writing an app for android where you play a game similar to Dutch Blitz. Its a pretty simple game, and I have it basically finished, I'm mostly looking for advice for how to handle my AI opponents, right now they win the game in about 2 seconds, I was wondering what i should do to get them to "pause" mid loop or how to slow them down some how so that the user has a chance to actually win.

I just don't want my way to slow them down dependent on the processor speed of the phone used...

Comment: i feel like i should mention that Dutch Blitz is a NON-TURN based game

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the game Dutch Blitz, but this logic should apply. You can create your turn functionality triggered by a [Count Down Timer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html). That function repeated (think of this as a turn) will eventually equate to a win condition. Causing your AI to prevale eventually, but not right away. You can then set the rate of how often a turn happens, thus controlling the rate at which your AI will win. Also this makes it easy to set difficulty levels by increasing the time it takes your AI to complete a turn.

Your game may work with different rules, but some kind of interval per turn would probably be the simple way to control the speed of your AI.

Comment: This along with maybe some randomization in the timer to simulate hesitation so it does not feel like they are playing a clockwork AI.

Comment: this totally makes since, and I'll use this in the future, but i'm not sure it'll work with my game mostly because its not actually turn based, so i just need to make the AI slow down and play at the same speed that a human might work..

Comment: no it will still work you just use the timer to slow down the computer let the player go as often as they want but only do the AI based on the timer. that is why some randomization will help it feel more natural...this is the best way to slow them down across any processor speed any other way will be processor dependent.

Comment: AJak is using the term turn loosely that is why he says you could control difficulty with it..Edit glad i could help get him some reputation he beat me to the answer lol

Comment: up vote for `Count Down Timer`, this is the first time I know about it, thanks.

Comment: @RustyH Yeah, should have put turn in quotes or explained the meaning a bit better. Thanks following up on my answer! I would have given the same advice.

Comment: @AJak no problem glad i could i help explain it.